# Error apt-get not found en Mac

Tags: macos

Al intentar instalar cocoapods en `MAC`, me aparece este error:

```
Designers-Mac:~ designer$ apt-get update
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

Cual puede ser el error?? He probado con mas comandos pero no me funcionan

Comment: Mac por defecto no trae `apt-get` instalado. En su defecto usa [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS no cuenta con ese gestor de paquetes. Una de las alternativas más usadas es Homebrew, aunque tambien existen otros como puedes ver aqui:
https://geekytheory.com/gestores-de-paquetes-en-mac-os-x/